# woocommerce_rest_cannot_create on jwt authentication

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using WordPress JWT auth along wp-rest API  and woocommerce. when I try to place an order from **subscriber account** through API its showing "**woocommerce_rest_cannot_create**". what is correct procedure to create an order by using woocommerce rest API using JWT auth.

```
 {
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

Comment: Was the current user id = 0? If so then authentication failed and the problem is not in WooCommerce but in your set up for JWT. Authentication is done by WordPress before WooCommerce is called and sets the current user. If authentication fails WordPress sets the current user id to 0.

Comment: To be clear, authentication is done independently from WooCommerce processing. WooCommerce is reporting the error because the current user id was set to 0 by an earlier authentication failure. This failure probably has nothing to do with WooCommerce. In other words, your setup to JWT is probably not correct.

Comment: No, the authentication is working fine. When I try to generate token it returns me the correct user id.@user9372991

Comment: Did you run the code I suggested to test that JWT has set the user for WooCommerce to use?

Comment: Yes I have tried still its showing same error.@user9372991

Comment: Was the current user id = 0? JWT Authentication is done in two phases. From your earlier comment I think the first phase is working. In the second phase you must pass back the generated token. Can you verify that your HTTP request has a Authorization header?

Comment: I have amended my answer with a check for the access token.

Comment: @SO-user - The plugin already has a very detailed explanation on how to use the plugin for authentication/authorization. Since, authentication/authorization is done independently of WooCommerce processing there is nothing special that needs to be done for WooCommerce. Of course, the HTTP request must have additional data for JWT ( in this case an HTTP Authorization header) but this data is orthogonal to the WooCommerce order data and is not processed by WooCommerce in any way. WooCommerce is not involved in JWT processing. The procedure would be the same for any application.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that you have setup JWT correctly by running the following code:

```
# From the file includes/class-jwt-auth.php of the JWT Authentication for WP REST API plugin
# find the priority of its filter 'determine_current_user' and set $priority to that priority + 1.
# The GitHub version has 10 so this sample uses 11.

$priority = 11;
add_filter( 'determine_current_user', function( $current_user_id ) {
    # If JWT Authentication has succeeded $current_user_id should be greater than 0
    error_log( 'current user id = '. $current_user_id );
    return $current_user_id;
}, $priority, 1 );
```

You can check that the access token is being received by running the following code:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    error_log("$header: $value";
}
```

There should be a header like the following:

```
Authorization: Bearer mF_s9.B5f-4.1JqM
```